# QBittorrent in ubuntu 22.04 is not opening ports

Tags: networking, qbittorrent, upnp

I don't know if this is happening to anyone else and might be a bug. I was using Kubuntu 21.10 until yesterday and QBittorrent was correctly using UPnP to do the port forwarding, however since I installed Ubuntu 22.04 yesterday, I've needed to manually configure the port forwarding on my router and manually open the ports in the firewall for QBittorrent to connect correctly.
Has anyone else seen this issue as well?

Comment: *I've needed to manually configure the port forwarding on my router and manually open the ports in the firewall for QBittorrent to connect correctly* **as you should**. UPnP should be avoided. But no, I don't know why it worked before and isn't working now.

Comment: Why is manual forwarding recommended? Is there a security flaw with UPnP?

Comment: UPnP can open ports without asking you, but that's what you wanted in the first place. It is only a security risk if the app is already compromised. UPnP uses SSDP so needs UDP incoming port 1900 to be let through the firewall to destination port 1900 to be working.